# How to access the Validator.required inside a custom component

Tags: angular

I need some help.  I'm trying to create a custom component that wraps a dropdown value and shows/hides the default --Select-- option depending upon whether it is required.  (And I want to apply other custom logic to this component later)

How do I get at the Validator.required within my custom control that is set via the reactive form of the parent??

I'm new to Angular but not AngularJS

*Parent page html:*

```
<div formGroupName="siteType">
    <my-dropdownlist 
        id="siteType"
        formControlName="code" 
        [items]="arrayOfItems">
    </my-dropdownlist>
</div>
```

*Parent page .ts:*

```
export class MyPage {

serviceForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    siteType: this.fb.group({
        code: [serviceData.siteType, Validators.required]  
    })
});
```

*Custom control html:*

```
<select class="form-control" id="itemType">
    <option *ngIf="!selectedValue && required">--Select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
        {{ item }}
    </option>
</select>
```

*Custom control ts:*

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, forwardRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl, Validator, NgForm, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-dropdownlist',
    templateUrl: './dropdownlist.component.html',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => DropdownListComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class MyDropdownListComponent implements Validator, OnInit {
    @Input() items: any[];
    @Input() required: boolean = false;
    @Input() formControlName: string;
    private selectedValue: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        //Some way to get at the Validator.required set on the parent form here so I can tell whether to apply it to my dropdown?
    }
    public validate(c: FormControl) {
        return null;  //TODO for additional future validation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumingly child should be a generic component for reusability. What I would do, is to pass the nested formcontrol and not the string. This results that you get the form control with all it's validators in it. At the same time, since you are getting the object, the parent will catch the changes made to the field as well. So pass the control:

```html
<my-dropdownlist 
  [ctrl]="serviceForm.controls.siteType.controls.code"
  [items]="arrayOfItems">
</my-dropdownlist>
```

Then of course change the `@Input` accordingly:

```html
@Input() items: any[];
@Input() ctrl: FormControl;
```

Since I can see in your code that you will have future validations, means that we can conditionally show the `--Select--` option just by checking if the form control is valid or with `ctrl.errors.required`:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="itemType" [formControl]="ctrl">
  <option *ngIf="!ctrl.valid" [ngValue]="null">--Select--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
    {{ item }}
  </option>
</select>
```

You can also get rid of the `NG_VALIDATORS` from the providers :)